# What can I do about the difference between adsense and analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, google-adsense

My adsense reports 12,000 monthly pageviews and my analytics reports 15,000 monthly pageviews. How can I act upon this difference and use adsense to fully monetize all the pageviews? Is there some way to see which pages are not with adsense on my site?

Comment: I thought originally that there would be a 30 day verses 28 day difference and so I thought I would test this theory comparing 30 days between both Adsense and Analytics. Long story short, there is still a difference. In my case, it is fairly large and for the life of me, I cannot figure out a reason why. I rather suspect this question would be better asked, Why is there a difference between the two? One up-vote for this question.

Comment: @closetnoc There can be several reasons for the discrepancy, apart from misconfiguration and pages without ads, ad-blocking software is likely to be a significant factor. And if ads are blocked it's a bit tricky to monetize them!

Comment: @w3d Yes. Of course! In my case, the difference between page views is 3x times. I am sure this is not due to ad blockers. In the OPs case, it is 2/3rds. That is a huge chunk of missing traffic. I guess what I am trying to say is How to monetize cannot be answered without knowing Why the difference. I am sure there is something huge out there and it would be interesting to know what it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google have answered this question for you:
https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/6090783?hl=en-GB

Might not exactly pinpoint the issue, but it really could be a whole lot of reasons. For one, are you absolutely certain that each and every pageview on your site is generating an ad impression?